# After Extracting from XML, need to map tag values into same java Object

Tags: java, xml, parsing

This is my XML Format , for which i am using STAX for parsing and putting them inside my java Object called as FormBean

```
<id>38400016</id>
<name>admin</name>
<Brd units="5" sold="15">
</Brd>
<Brd units="5" sold="15">
</Brd>
<Brd units="5" sold="15">
</Brd>

class FormBean 
{
double units;
double sold;
String name;
String id ;
}
```

**See the  way i am doing parsing using STAX**

```
if (startElementName.equals("Brd")) 
{
FormBean formbean = new FormBean();
// Here i am getting the attributes from Brd and setting them into FormBean
// as shown in below way
formbean.units = attribute.getValue(); // sets the unit value into FormBean 
}

if (startElementName.equals("name")) 
{

}
```

Now my question is , how can i set the name and id variables also  within the same  FormBean  as i cant create a new instance of FormBean  inside a id or an name tags ??

And at last i am adding these FormBean to an arrayList .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a library like

- [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)
- [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/)
- [JiBX](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/)

To do all the heavy lifting for you?